# Using the data to obtain a prior for an analysis of that same data?

Tags: bayesian, prior

I am refereeing a physics paper in which the authors first analyze their data using a low-accuracy method, and then use the result of that method as a prior to re-analyze the data using a higher-accuracy method. Is this actually valid? To me this seems like it would be double-dipping, but I wanted to ask some experts before I object.

Comment: That is completely invalid.  A perfect example of double-dipping.

Comment: Also, depending on details, might be a valid example of [Empirical Bayes method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method).